# Must Lost Focus When no Item is Selected in a List View

Tags: .net, vb.net, listview, lost-focus

I believe this is quite easy but I'm currently having problems with this right now.
I have a list view and every time I click on an item, I'm storing its name on a string variable. What happens is that when I click an item on the list view and then click inside the list view again without selecting any item, it doesn't lost focus and stores the name of the previous selected item on the string variable. What I want to happen is that every time I click an item and then click inside or outside the list view without selecting any item, it must lost focus and not store the name of the item on a string variable.

```
Private Sub lvReceivedFiles_MouseClick(sender As Object, e As System.Windows.Forms.MouseEventArgs) Handles lvReceivedFiles.MouseClick

    If e.Button = Windows.Forms.MouseButtons.Left Then

        If lvRecievedFiles.FocusedItem.Selected = True

              lvReceivedFiles.FullRowSelect = True

              'When an item is clicked in the list view, store its name.
              fName = "\" & Path.GetFileName(lvReceivedFiles.FocusedItem.Text)

        Else

              'This part here doesn't make any sense because it doesn't execute
              'every time I click in the list view without selecting any item.
              'ListView.FocusedItem.Selected is always true.

        End If

    End If

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try in `MouseUp event`.

```
Private Sub lvlcheckin_MouseUp(sender As Object, e As MouseEventArgs) Handles lvlcheckin.MouseUp
    If e.Button = Windows.Forms.MouseButtons.Left Then

        If lvlcheckin.FocusedItem.Selected = True Then
            lvlcheckin.FullRowSelect = True
        Else
            lvlcheckin.FullRowSelect = False
        End If
    End If
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

The better way to handle this situation would be to use SelectedIndexChanged event instead of using MouseClick event. Check this code.

```
Private Sub ListView1_SelectedIndexChanged(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles lvReceivedFiles.SelectedIndexChanged

If lvRecievedFiles.FocusedItem.Selected = True

          lvReceivedFiles.FullRowSelect = True

          'When an item is clicked in the list view, store its name.
          fName = "\" & Path.GetFileName(lvReceivedFiles.FocusedItem.Text)

Else

          'This part here doesn't make any sense because it doesn't execute
          'every time I click in the list view without selecting any item.
          'ListView.FocusedItem.Selected is always true.

End If

End Sub
```